# AutoMapper map inherited properties from subclass

Tags: c#, automapper

In my data I have two entities that can have an address. In the database these columns are duplicated in each table. I might normalize those in the future, but don't want to tackle it at the moment. In my view model, however, I do have the contact info broken out into a separate class that is reused.

I'm trying to figure out an elegant way to map the properties in this situation.  Mapping from the database to the view models is easy enough, but I'm struggling with the reverse - view model to database model.

Here are the data entity classes (simplified a little):

```
public abstract class EntityWithContactInfo
{
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Street1 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Street2 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Organization : EntityWithContactInfo
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100), Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100), Required]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string Website { get; set; }

    public string Information { get; set; }
}

public class Agent : EntityWithContactInfo
{
    public int AgentId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30), Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20), Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And here are my view models (I don't have one for Agent yet - working on Organization first):

```
public class ContactInfoEditModel
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Street Address 1")]
    public string Street1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Street Address 2")]
    public string Street2 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pimary Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public abstract class EditModelBaseWithContactInfo
{
    [Display(Name = "Contact Information")]
    public ContactInfoEditModel ContactInfo { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationEditModel : EditModelBaseWithContactInfo
{
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Display Name")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [Url(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid URL (including the protocol: http:// or https://).")]
    public string Website { get; set; }

    [UIHint("HtmlEditor")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Information { get; set; }
}
```

What I have for mappings right now look like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityWithContactInfo, ContactInfoEditModel>();

Mapper.CreateMap<Organization, OrganizationEditModel>()
      .MapEditModelBaseWithContactInfo();

Mapper.CreateMap<OrganizationEditModel, Organization>()
      .MapEntityWithContactInfo();


private static IMappingExpression<TEntity, TModel> MapEditModelBaseWithContactInfo<TEntity, TModel>(this IMappingExpression<TEntity, TModel> mapping)
    where TEntity : EntityWithContactInfo
    where TModel : EditModelBaseWithContactInfo
{
    return mapping.ForMember(m => m.ContactInfo, exp => exp.MapFrom(e => Mapper.Map<ContactInfoEditModel>(e)));
}

private static IMappingExpression<TModel, TEntity> MapEntityWithContactInfo<TModel, TEntity>(this IMappingExpression<TModel, TEntity> mapping)
    where TModel : EditModelBaseWithContactInfo
    where TEntity : EntityWithContactInfo
{
    return mapping.MapEntityModifiable()
                  .ForMember(e => e.Street1, exp => exp.MapFrom(m => m.ContactInfo.Street1))
                  .ForMember(e => e.Street2, exp => exp.MapFrom(m => m.ContactInfo.Street2))
                  .ForMember(e => e.City, exp => exp.MapFrom(m => m.ContactInfo.City))
                  .ForMember(e => e.State, exp => exp.MapFrom(m => m.ContactInfo.State))
                  .ForMember(e => e.Zip, exp => exp.MapFrom(m => m.ContactInfo.Zip))
                  .ForMember(e => e.Email, exp => exp.MapFrom(m => m.ContactInfo.Email))
                  .ForMember(e => e.State, exp => exp.MapFrom(m => m.ContactInfo.State))
                  .ForMember(e => e.Phone, exp => exp.MapFrom(m => m.ContactInfo.Phone));
}
```

I made the last two extension methods in my static mapping class so that when I add the Agent mappings I don't have to duplicate the .ForMember calls. As you can see, the mapping from data model to view model looks good. The second extension method, though, is where I'm struggling. It works just fine, but it doesn't seem like the **right** way to do it. As you can see, I have all of the properties on Organization/ContactInfo listed out explicitly, even though they all have the same names (which AutoMapper usually handles itself)

It seems like there should be a way to tell AutoMapper to map all properties on the ContactInfo property of the Source directly onto the Destination. Does anyone know how you'd do this? I played with Include<> and IncludeBase<>.

I also considered having OrganizationEditModel inherit from ContactInfoEditModel directly, but I wasn't sure if that might mess up my EditorTemplates (and that still feels like a workaround and not the **right** solution).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into `ConvertUsing`. The second extension method could look like:

```
private static IMappingExpression<TModel, TEntity> MapEntityWithContactInfo<TModel, TEntity>(this IMappingExpression<TModel, TEntity> mapping)
    where TModel : EditModelBaseWithContactInfo
    where TEntity : EntityWithContactInfo
{
    return mapping.MapEntityModifiable()
        .ConvertUsing(x => Mapper.Map<TEntity>(x.ContactInfo));
}
```

Comment: I tried that, and it required a mapping from ContactInfoEditModel to Organization (with Ignore() clauses for all of the Organization-specific fields), but now the mapping isn't copying **any** of the data from the view model to the data model.